# Возможно ли сохранить layout в VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Возможно ли сохранить layout в VSCode? Вроде бы я не замечал в обновлениях настройки для него, которые были бы для всех редакторов/проектов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Ролик на ютубе](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mjlHgQ2ThG4), демонстрирующий проблему.

Ожидаемое расположение, при открытии любого файла:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

... но при закрытии всех "вкладок" и открытии любых файлов сбрасывает все.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что именно имеется в виду? он как бы и так сохраняется. Или нужно чтобы он был один и тот же для всех проектов? Как минимум есть возможность настроить стартовый вид.

Comment: `Как минимум есть возможность настроить стартовый вид` можно подробнее?

Comment: Под `стартовым видом` я имею в виду настройку которая используется пока не cоздан никакой проект. И настраивается он соответственно тоже в это время, т.е. открываем пустой vscode настраиваем все как нам нужно (`ручками`, не конфигом) и закрываем, после чего каждый раз при начале нового проекта будет один и тот же вид пока мы что-то не поменяем в процессе работы над проектом.

Comment: К сожалению, оно не сохраняет вид. Я часто запускаю редактор, чтобы  написать код в новом отдельном файле, который не особо то и является проектом.

Comment: Не знаю почему, но в моем случае все сохраняется, правда у меня Codium, но думаю разницы быть не должно. Для одно файловых небольших проектов я использую саблайм - мне кажется он намного шустрее для этого.

Comment: В саблайме нет нужного функционала.

Comment: Я воспользовался приведенным выше меню и у меня теперь боковая панель справа, какой бы проект не открыл. Кстати про функционал какой именно нужен? вполне возможно что он там есть

Comment: `Кстати про функционал какой именно нужен? вполне возможно что он там есть` Я думаю это не имеет значение ибо мне удобно использовать VSC для всех задач и он быстро запускается.

Comment: Понятно:) Вот снял [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H2R_FNZ45iM) чтобы показать как у меня

Comment: То, что данная панелька сохраняет свою позицию, это то понятно. В вопросе есть ссылка на видео, в чем именно проблема.

Comment: Центрирование я проверял, оно не сохраняется :(, если вопрос про него

Comment: Центрирование и левая панель (в данном случае "outline")

Comment: Нашел решение нужно `"zenMode.hideTabs": false` и открывать папки только из запущенного vscode чтобы ничего не ломалось

Comment: Это не удовлетворительное решение, так что, буду дальше что-то гадать..

Comment: Потому что папку нужно открывать изнутри? папку можно передать в командной строке думаю , просто точкой

Comment: У меня так работает (`codium .`) другое дело если командная строка смущает, тут я пас

Comment: Еще я заметил что если убрать галочку в меню `Show Active Bar`  то отображаться будут 2 панели и больше не нужно танцев с запуском и вообще, на этом у меня все)

Answer (score 0):

Конечено, же вы можете создать `settings.json` для одного конкретного проекта, который помещаете в папку `.vscode`. В этом файле вы укзываете настройки для своего `layout`.

Пример

```json
{
    "workbench.sideBar.location": "right",
    "workbench.activityBar.visible": true,
    "workbench.panel.defaultLocation": "bottom",
    "zenMode.centerLayout": true
}
```

Так же, вы можете использовать <kbd>F1</kbd> => `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)` и прописать данные настройки для пользователя, глобально.

Comment: Именно такие настройки у меня и установлены.  Но при запуске я не получаю то, что ожидаю.

Comment: @OliverPatterson выглядит как баг, я не замечал такого поведения

Comment: @OliverPatterson протестил, в том числе и `Settings Sync`. На одной машине поменял, на другой после синхронизации настройки встали как надо

Comment: Я добавил в вопрос скриншот, как должно выглядеть при открытии какого либо нового файла.

Comment: Нет, мне не нужен zen мод.

Comment: @OliverPatterson  я не могу смоделировать ситуацию( как все прописал в настройках, так и открывается, вне зависимости как и что я открываю

Comment: Я открываю просто редактор, не файл. Настраиваю как мне нужно, дальше я закрываю редактор, открываю какой-то файл, и все что я настраивал - оно не сохраняется. Если настраивать все это для проекта (когда открываешь папку), то все нормально. Если я просто отредактировал редактор, и там было что-то открыто, закрываю редактор, открываю файл какой-то - тоже все нормально.

Comment: Добавил ссылку на ролик.

Comment: @OliverPatterson посмотрел, это show/hide функциональность, дело не в настройках layouta. Попробую раскопать решение

Comment: Есть подозрение, что на данный момент это не реализовано.